# Redirect subdomain in IIS via web.config file

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

Looking to redirect old subdomain back to the primary domain name (remove the subdomain if it's seen) in the web.config file for IIS.

For example,
preview.mysite.com                  redirects to    mysite.com

The rule I've tried is this:

```
<rule name="Redirect away from Preview" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="preview.mysite.com" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

It stops preview subdomain from loading, but shows error message instead of doing a redirect

**This page isn’t working
preview.mysite.com redirected you too many times.**

What can I do to correct the redirect rule to reroute any preview subdomain back to the base domain?

Comment: If you enable FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules you will see IIS strictly followed your incorrect rule to perform the redirection and of course endlessly. Your target URL in `action` tag must be different to avoid that (which you fixed in the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed. Had to hardcode the redirect url and that fixed the looping issue, now redirects to the main domain:

```
<rule name="Redirect away from Preview" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="preview.mysite.com" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Hope this helps someone else. (Note: stackoverflow would not allow me to put mysite for the url so it shows example.com instead)